# Im(A) = Im(A*A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How does one prove that $Im(A^*) = Im(A^*A)$ and that the $Im(A) = Im(AA^*)$?

I have found that $Ker(A) = Ker(A^*A)$ and that $Ker(A)=Ker(AA^{*})$.  Also, the $Rank(A) = Rank(AA^{*}) = Rank(A^{*}A)$.

EDIT: A is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Is $A$ a square matrix? If it is not square, $Im(A)$ and $Im(A^*A)$ are in different spaces and their equality is not very meaningful.

Comment: A is an $m \times n$ matrix.  See above edits, should make more sense.

Comment: The equality of the ranges follows from the equality of the kernels.

Comment: I really don't see how it follows.

Comment: Think matrix rank and dimensions. Useful fact: If one finite dimensional space is contained in the other and their dimensions are the same, the spaces are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof that Im$(A^*A)=$Im$(A^*)$.

Clearly, Im$(A^*A)\le\,$Im$(A^*)$. If $\,x\perp\,$Im$(A^*A)$, then 
$$
\langle x, A^*Ay\rangle=0,\quad\text{for all $y$},
$$
or
$$
\langle Ax, Ay\rangle=0,\quad\text{for all $y$},
$$
or
$$
\langle A^*Ax, y\rangle=0,\quad\text{for all $y$},
$$
or $x\in\,$ker$\,(A^*A)$, and hence
$$
0=\langle x,A^*Ax\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle,
$$
or $Ax=0$ or $\,x\in\,$ker$\,(A)\,$ or for every $y$
$$
0=\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle,
$$
which means that $x\perp\mathrm{Im}(A^*)$.

Thus $\mathrm{Im}(A^*)=\mathrm{Im}(A^*A)$.

Comment: A is an $m \times n$ matrix.  Sorry, I forgot to put that in the main question.

Comment: @Snagglewhen You can write the exact same argument word for word even when $A$ isn't square.